# Cannot start MySQL Server after stopping it running on localhost by mistake

Tags: mysql, database, localhost, mysql-workbench

I was trying workbench around and stopped the MySQL server running on localhost by mistake. Then I tried to restart it from the workbench and windows powershell. It did not work. I uninstalled MySQL and installed it again from scratch. But that did not help too. I tried all the ways given on the StackOverflow too. That did not work either

Windows is not even showing MySQL in the services window, even if I reinstall it. Even powershell is giving error, service name (MYSQL) is invalid

Kindly let me know how can I restart the MySQL server. Thanking you in anticipation.

I am attaching the error message below

```
2021-03-23 06:23:54 - Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance
2021-03-23 06:23:54 - Checking server status...
2021-03-23 06:23:54 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2021-03-23 06:23:54 - Unable to connect to localhost (2003)
2021-03-23 06:23:54 - Assuming server is not running
Could not open error log file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\data\\ABHIJEET.err'
2021-03-23 06:23:59 - Starting server...
2021-03-23 06:23:59 - Could not start server: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Checking server status...
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Unable to connect to localhost (2003)
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Assuming server is not running
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Checking server status...
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Unable to connect to localhost (2003)
2021-03-23 06:24:05 - Assuming server is not running
```

Comment: Um MySQL != SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score -1):

I am not so much familiar with Workbench but I think somehow port number is clashing with some other application.